# Difference in rotated image when using cv.rotate and cv.warpAffine

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

I have observed that there is a difference between rotation using cv.warpAffine method and the cv.rotate method. The resulting images are different - while cv.rotate is perfect i.e. rotated image with no parts of the image getting cutoff, cv.warpAffine generates an image that has part of the image cutoff. The example image and the results of the 2 methods are attached.

Configuration: python:3.9.13; opencv-python 4.7.0; Windows 10

*Samples*:

original:

[image: 1]

cv.rotate:

[image: 2]

cv.warpAffine:

[image: 3]

*Code to reproduce problem*

```
>>> img = cv.imread(<path to image>, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
>>> rot_img = cv.rotate(img, cv.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
>>> cv.imwrite('cv_rotate.jpg', rot_img)
True
>>> img_center = (img.shape[1]//2, img.shape[0]//2)
>>> M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(img_center, 90, 1)
>>> rot_img = cv.warpAffine(img, M, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
>>> cv.imwrite('cv_warpAffine.jpg', rot_img)
True
```

I was expecting both the methods to generate the same output. Why is there a difference? I have tried a few other ways anticipating that I am messing up the (row, col) format with the (x, y) format (why OpenCV uses a different style even when producing ndarray output I don't know) but those did not work. Can someone please let me know what's the issue here?

Comment: `size` is the size of the output image, but you have used the size of the input image, I think.  What happens if you swap `img.shape[0]`, and `img.shape[1]`?  But for pixel perfect rotations, you probably want the cv.rotate function, not cv.warpaffine.  You may find other minor imperfections on a warp affine operation at 90 degrees, due to floating point stuff.

Comment: Well the size is taken in the (width, height) and img.shape gives it in (height, width) or (row, col) format, So after I rotate I want the dimensions to be inverted in the rotated image. Using that the dimensions of the resulting image match that of the cv.rotate.

Comment: cv.rotate might have specialized implementations for 0, 90, 180, 270 and 360 degrees. Do you see similar differences for 45 degrees for example?

Comment: I haven't checked for 45 degrees. I don't need it. What concerns me is that using warpAffine to rotate about the center cutsoff the image at the edges. And that is by some considerable amount.

Comment: For 90 degree rotations, use [`np.rot90`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html), you don’t need interpolation, nor difficult math to get the origin right. It just swaps the axes and inverts one. I think it does all of that without even copying data. You won’t get more efficient than this one.

Comment: `cv.rotate()` only rotates by multiples of 90 degrees. in that regard, it is specialized because it doesn't interpolate ever, but it returns new data. `np.rot90()` probably just manipulates the strides and gives you a lightweight view on the source data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need 90 degree rotations, stick with `cv.rotate()`. This rotates in steps of 90 degrees. It does not resample or interpolate.

In the comments, Cris Luengo suggests `np.rot90()`, which potentially is an extremely cheap operation because numpy can just calculate new strides and give you a view on the original data. `cv.rotate()` does not do that because the internally used `cv::Mat` isn't as flexible as a numpy array.

---

You can achieve the desired result with `cv.getRotationMatrix2D()` if the center of rotation is correct.

If you pick the center of the *rectangle*, that will just rotate the image around that point, and result in what you've already seen: the result is the green rectangle, with the **red** rectangle representing the image content.

[image: rotate around center]

If the top left origins of source and result coincide, the "correct" center of rotation for a 90 degree rotation of a rectangle depends on the rectangle's side lengths and the direction of the rotation. Consider two squares, one for each side length of the rectangle. The center of rotation lies in the center of one or the other square, depending on direction.

```
...
>>> ih, iw = img.shape[:2]
>>> img_center = (iw-1)/2, (iw-1)/2
>>> M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(img_center, +90, 1)
...
```

```
>>> img_center = (ih-1)/2, (ih-1)/2
>>> M = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(img_center, -90, 1)
```

[image: center point and getRotationmatrix2D]
[image: rotated the other way, with center point]

---

You can also build your own transformation from primitives:

```
def translate(tx=0, ty=0):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[:2, 2] = (tx, ty)
    return T

def rotate(angle):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[:2, :] = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((0,0), angle, 1)
    # it's rotating counterclockwise in X-right, Y-down
    return T

angle = 90

(ih, iw) = img.shape[:2]
ow,oh = ih,iw # only valid for 90 degree rotation

icx, icy = (iw-1)/2, (ih-1)/2
ocx, ocy = (ow-1)/2, (oh-1)/2

T = translate(+ocx, +ocy) @ rotate(angle) @ translate(-icx, -icy)

rot_img = cv.warpAffine(img, M=T[:2], dsize=(ow, oh))
```

[image: rot_img]

---

To warp *points* instead of images, there is the function `cv.transform()` for affine transformations.

Points need to be given as a numpy array of shape `(N, 2)` or `(N, 1, 2)`.

For perspective transforms, there is `cv.perspectiveTransform()`. It takes care of the "division by w".

Comment: This solution is exactly what I need. I will check once on my other data. I need the rotation matrix as I have some bounding boxes that I am detecting on the rotated image that I need to rotate back to co-ordinates in the original image. Hence, I am inclined on using warpAffine and not cv.rotate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution to this problem. It was getting weirdly tedious. One last question - how did you understand that the center is not being rotated in warpAffine?

Comment: to warp _points_, you can use `cv.transform()`, which applies the transformation to a numpy array of points. there's also `perspectiveTransform()` that even "divides by w" for you, in case you have to deal with perspective transforms, not just affine ones

Comment: `warpAffine()` doesn't deal with centers at all. it purely applies the matrix. -- the issue is with the `getRotationMatrix2D()` call. it rotates around the point you give. nothing more. -- the correct center of rotation for a 90 degree rotation of a **rectangle** depends on the direction of the rotation and its side lengths. consider two squares, one for each side length. the center of rotation lies in the center of one or the other, depending on direction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The requirement is the transformation matrix because I said I need to rotate back bounding boxes as well after processing the ROI in them. In the solution that you gave me to do this I just take the matrix [T_inv = translate(+icx, +icy) @ rotate(-angle) @translate(-ocx, -ocy)] and then T_inv[:2].

Comment: `np.linalg.inv()` will do just fine. no need to invert each part of the composed transform.

Comment: Aha completely missed it. I thought its a 2x3 matrix and not 3x3 which required the pseudo-inverse.